# Rails 4 + Sunspot: searching things a User has "liked" by their attributes (polymorphic has_many through associations)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, full-text-search, polymorphic-associations, sunspot

I have something like the following in a Rails 4 app:

```
class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :liker, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :likeable, polymorphic: true
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  # has a `title` and `description` attributes
  has_many :likes, as: likeable
  has_many :likers, through: :likes
end

class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  # has a `title` and `description` attributes
  has_many :likes, as: likeable
  has_many :likers, through: :likes
end

class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  # has a `title` and `description` attributes
  has_many :likes, as: likeable
  has_many :likers, through: :likes
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :likes, source: :liker
  has_many :liked_photos, through: :likes, source: :likeable, source_type: 'Photo'
  has_many :liked_videos, through: :likes, source: :likeable, source_type: 'Video'
  has_many :liked_songs, through: :likes, source: :likeable, source_type: 'Song'
end
```

I would like to have a search form where the current user can search for photos, songs, and videos by their `title` or `description` but have results be scoped by only those that he/she has liked. I've read some other posts dealing with has_many search, but I'm getting confused on the polymorphic side of things. I was thinking the search would be something like this:

```
@search = Sunspot.search(Photo, Song, Video) { fulltext params[:term] }
```

But then I got confused how to scope it by current_user.likes. Or should the search be on the `Like` model? For example:

```
@search = Like.search { fulltext params[:term] }
```

What should be included in the `searchable` method, and in which model(s) does this best belong?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing:

```
class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    text :likeable_title do
      likeable.title
    end
    text :likeable_description do
      likeable.description
    end
    integer :liker_id
  end
end
```

Then I could do the following search in a controller

```
@search = Like.search(include: :likeable) do
            fulltext params[:term]
            with :liker_id, current_user.id
          end
```

I can then render the view using the `likeable` for each result. Let me know if you have a better way or if there is something I'm not considering...

Comment: if you dont mind, could you please review my question related to your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42345963/rails-sunspot-with-polymorphic-association

Comment: @LearningROR, I haven't really worked with Rails or Sunspot for the last couple years, so I'm probably not a good resource at this point.